# Autoloading - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using `PHP 7.1` and I am trying to run the following package, [BladeOne](https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne).

In my php file I have the following code:

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";

use eftec\bladeone;

$views = __DIR__ . '/views';
$cache = __DIR__ . '/cache';
define("BLADEONE_MODE", 1); // (optional) 1=forced (test),2=run fast (production), 0=automatic, default value.
$blade = new bladeone\BladeOne($views,$cache); // HERE I GET AN ERROR
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'eftec\bladeone\BladeOne' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/blade-autoload.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/ubuntu/workspace/blade-autoload.php on line 9
```

My composer.json file looks like the following:

```
{
    "name": "blade-one",
    "authors": [{
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    }],
    "require": {
        "eftec/bladeone": "^3.0"
        }
}
```

I used `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` to install the package and then to regenerate the autoload file. However, this does not work.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the autoloader definition in v3.0: https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne/blob/3.0/composer.json - this looks wrong, it's just `eftec\\` and should be `eftec\\bladeone\\`. Seems to be fixed in current `master`.

This issue looks relevant: https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne/issues/26

And the history shows he had some struggles: https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne/commits/master/composer.json

So you should make sure you got the fixed/latest version.